# How can you acccess a discord message via discrod.js when you have the channel and the message ID but not the original message object?

Tags: discord.js

I am trying to build a json back up file that will relaunch my discord.js bot in the event of crashes. The bot is a simple countdown that edits the message to show the time remaining.

So far I have managed to save the channel id to json and can reconnect to the channel via the id on relauch - 
`myChannel = Client.channels.get(myChannelID);`

but I cannot find a way to connect back to the message without having a message object, or how to store the message object in json.

I can easily get the message id and save it but cant seem to find the method to use that id to connect to the message, any help appreciated

Answer (score 2):

@aci It is not likely to work as per the new discord.js V12.1.1. I would request Wayne to check the discord.js version from Package.json. if it is above discord.js v12.0.x, then you are supposed to use the following :

```js
let mychannel = client.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.Id == "ChannelId")
let loadmsg = mychannel.cache.fetchMessage("msgid")
```

else wise, you can use the name of the channel if it is a bot meant for a single server :

```js
let mychannel = client.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name == "ChannelName")
let loadmsg = mychannel.cache.fetchMessage("msgid")
```

Comment: Great thanks for that, I would add that in order to do anything with the fetched message I found that I had to do so in a .then section when the promis is returned - 
`let countdownMessage = countdownChannel.fetchMessage(countdownMessageID)
    .then(relinkedCountdownMsg => startTimer(relinkedCountdownMsg))`

Answer (score 0):

You can first get the channel with the ID, then get the message with the channel and message id:

```js
let mychannel = bot.channels.get("ChannelID");
let message = mychannel.fetchMessage("MsgID");
```